# Gather all turtles together

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have the following code. The last function of the code should gather the children to their mother.

```py
class MotherTurtle(Turtle):  
    def __init__(self, home):
        Turtle.__init__(self, home)
        self.children = []
        self.home = home
        self.setName("Mum")
        
    def giveBirth(self, name):
        newborn = Turtle(self.home)
        newborn.setName (name)
        self.children.append(newborn)
        return newborn
        
    def greetChildren(self):
        for child in self.children:
            print "Hi %s" %(child.name)
                
    def gatherChildren(self):
        for child in self.children:
            child.moveTo(self.home)
```

I need to gather the children to their mother.

[image]

This is the error I get when I run the program:

```
======= Loading Progam =======
>>> world = makeWorld()
>>> mum = MotherTurtle(world)
>>> mary = mum.giveBirth("Mary")
>>> jimmy = mum.giveBirth("Jimmy")
>>> mum.greetChildren()
Hi Mary
Hi Jimmy
>>> mary.turn(-45)
>>> mary.forward(120)
>>> jimmy.turn(90)
>>> jimmy.forward()
>>> mum.gatherChildren()
```

The error was:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'moveTo'
> Attribute not found.
> You are trying to access a part of the object that doesn't exist.
> Please check line 21 of C:\Users\user\Desktop\159171

Comment: Does the error have a stack trace?  Can you share it?

Comment: You should also go and accept some of the answers on your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```py
def gatherChildren(self):
    
    # get the position of the mother turtle    
    mumX = self.getXPos()
    mumY = self.getYPos()
    # use an offset so not all turtles are on top of each other
    spacing = 10
    offset = spacing
    # loop through the list of children to place each child close to the mother
    for child in self.children:
      child.moveTo(mumX + offset, mumY + offset)
      offset = offset + spacing
```